# php run shell_exec with unique characters

Tags: php, linux

i'm using one of python script for video upload to youtube.

im trigger this python script on php like this.

```
$result3 = escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/youtube-upload --title="' . $title . '" --client-secrets=/usr/share/youtube_upload/client_secrets.json --credentials-file=/usr/share/youtube_upload/credential.json ' . $filename . ' 2>&1');

$res5 = shell_exec($result3);
```

But title some time contains Turkish characters and shell_exec never work with turkish characters,but I've tried this command on ssh and its worked good.

when i use escapeshellcmd command,its removing turkish characters and there is no sense for me.

How can i run this script with Turkish characters ?

------im fixed this--------

1-write shell command to txt file by php.
2-trigger read.py from php shell_exec
3-read txt file by python and send shell command os.system function.

read.py first line should be `# -*- coding: iso-8859-9 -*-` for Turkish characters

im fixed like this and i learned a little bit python